# How to add new origins to an already existing cloudfront distribution through Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to add an origin to existing CF using terraform. I could not find any block that could retrieve CF config and add origin. please advise

Comment: Please add any code you currently have to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you would not want this CloudFront distribution to be managed by this terraform state?
Because I would usually think my distribution and origins on that distribution should be together...

I do not know of a way to separate the two, but if you would want to yes manage them together - I would import the existing distribution and add the distribution resource - with an extra origin block for the new origin - to the desired terraform state.

Starting from terraform V1.5, you can import also using code - not only by the cli:

```
import {
    to = aws_cloudfront_distribution.distribution
    id = "E74FTE3EXAMPLE"
}
```

Comment: The question is about having multiple origins, not about importing a distribution.